# SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration React-Native

Tags: react-native

I am making database connection with React-native. I want to capture the data I saved elsewhere in this class. But I'm having the problem I wrote below.

Error Code: const warnedKeys: {[string]: boolean} = {};

```
const AsyncStorage = require('react-native');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

const db = mysql.createConnection({

});

db.connect();
  AsyncStorage.getItem('155').then(value =>

 console.log(value)
    );

app.get('/', function(req,res){
var sql = 'SELECT ID FROM ...TBL_STT';
db.query(sql, (err, result)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
});
});


app.listen(3210, ()=>{
    console.log('Server aktif di port 3210')
});
```

Comment: Why are you using React Native on the server?

Comment: Because I want to capture the data I recorded. @Ziyo

Answer (score 0):

There is no value assigned to your `db` variable. The `const` must be assigned an unconditional value, such as a letter in JavaScript.

You can change this value `const db => let db`

```js
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
...
let db = mysql.createConnection({ });
```

Comment: The problem continues. I'm having this problem when I define the AsyncStorage variable.

Comment: @SHYazılımGeliştirme Please look at my revised answer.

Comment: Error Code: "import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"